# Instantiate a derived class of List<T> at runtime using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a generic `class MyList<T> : MyBaseClass, IList<T>` which accepts an unknown amount of unknown element types.
Somewhere else I declare some custom lists **BUT** without instantiating them (*it is a must due to some general restrictions*):

```
MyList<MyObjectType1> type1List1, type1List2,... ;
MyList<MyObjectType2> type2List1, type2List2,... ;
```

I would like to instantiate those custom lists at runtime using reflection:

```
foreach (FieldInfo field in this.GetType().GetFields())
{
   if (field.FieldType == typeof(MyList<>)) // this condition is **NEVER** passed!
   {
      MyList<>valueToSet = new MyList<>(); // does not work, needs type
      MyList<T>valueToSet = new MyList<T>(); // does not work, there's no T
      MyList<...?...>valueToSet = new MyList<...?...>(); // how can i put here the type?
      field.SetValue(this, valueToSet);
      ...
   }
}
```

The problems I encountered are that, thus the type of the objects used in each of the declared lists is unknown untill runtime, I can not find an expression to use in my code for the instantiation `MyList<...?...>valueToSet = new MyList<...?...>()`, as well as that surprisingly (at least for me) the expression `if (field.FieldType == typeof(MyList<>))` never passes.

Just in case suggested please be aware that, due to some class dependencies and constraints I can not create an interface for `MyList<T>`.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:**
Thanks to [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59702524/12445601) and to [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59703241/12445601) i could solve **completelly** this issue

Comment: Because you already declared the collections _"somewhere else"_ you can simply call `new DeclaredCollectionType()`. Why do you need reflection? Sounds like deferred instantiation. You may also use `Lazy<T>` to create type instance deferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part is that to do the comparison what you are really looking for is a comparison of the field type's generic type definition. Change your if statement to use GetGenericTypeDefinition to check that:

```
if (field.FieldType.IsGenericType && field.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyList<>))
```

Next you've got to construct an instance of a type you don't know, Activator.CreateInstance is usually the simplest way to do this:

```
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(field.FieldType);
field.SetValue(this, list);
```

Now one thing I notice is that we are setting fields on the current object. This is a bit unusual. Why is that? Don't you know all these types at compile time?

Comment: Thanks, your approach solved my issues! I would still like to catch the name of the instantiated class and save it into a custom property, therefore I have edited my post to add this concern; may you have as well a hint for this?

Comment: @anna - If you have a further question please ask it as one. Don't get answers and then go "whoops, I needed more". If Mike's answered your first question then accept it and ask a new one. Otherwise it makes Mike look like a dick for not answering the full question.

Comment: Do you have anyway a hint to solve the part `valueToSet.MyName = field.Name`? I already tried defining my custom class as `class MyList<dynamic> : MyBaseClass, IList<dynamic>´ but still breaks at ´valueToSet.MyName = field.Name´

Comment: Right! (+1) worked as well, and it looks more compact!

Comment: @Sweeper Yup. It was late and I totally missed the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible to use  `MyList<dynamic>` in your use case?

e.g

```
type1List1 = new List<dynamic>(); 
type1List1.Add(new MyObjectType1()); 
MyObjectType1 element = type1List1.ElementAt(0);
```

Basically dynamic is a special type that can have any properties - effectively gaining some benefits of a more loosely typed language like JavaScript into C#. You can add any kind of object to your MyList. You'll just have to keep track of the types in each one manually in your code and make sure you know what type you're expecting when you wish to use them

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic

Comment: I didn't know about this type, could you please propose me a use case?

Comment: Basically dynamic is a special type that can have any properties - effectively gaining some benefits of a more loosely typed language like JavaScript into C#.
You can add anykind of object to your MyList<dynamic>. You'll just have to keep track of the types in each one manually in your code and make sure you know what type you're expecting when you wish to use them.

            ```type1List1 = new List<dynamic>();
            type1List1.Add(new MyObjectType1());

            MyObjectType1 element = type1List1.ElementAt(0);```

Comment: @AdamDiament Why not put all that information in your answer?

Comment: Seems this does not work for me... I modified my code to use `dynamics` as you proposed, but when coming to the piece of code where I try to instantiate using reflection, the part `valueToSet.MyName = field.Name` breaks with error `System.ArgumentException HResult=0x80070057 Message=Object of type objects.MyList 1[System.Object] cannot be converted to type objects.MyList 1[MyNameSpace.MyObjectType1]...
`