# Set property on a derived class of List<T> instantiated at runtime using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am using reflection to instantiate a custom class `class MyList : MyBaseClass, IList´:

```
foreach (FieldInfo field in this.GetType().GetFields())
{
   if (field.FieldType.IsGenericType && field.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyList<>))
   {
      var elementType = field.FieldType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
      var listType = typeof(MyList<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
      var valueToSet= Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
      field.SetValue(this, valueToSet);
      ...
      valueToSet.MyName = field.Name; // does not work because "valueToSet" does not recognize this property
      ...
   }
}
```

The problem is, that the part `valueToSet.MyName = field.Name` does not recognize the property `MyName` that my custom class `MyList<T>` has. I also tried defining my `MyList<T>` as `class MyList<dynamic> : MyBaseClass, IList<dynamic>` but the `valueToSet.MyName = field.Name` part throws now the error `System.ArgumentException HResult=0x80070057 Message=Object of type objects.MyList 1[System.Object] cannot be converted to type objects.MyList 1[MyNameSpace.MyObjectType1]...`

Any hint on how to resolve this? I would like to keep my original declaration without `dynamics`
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry! it was a typo... already corrected in my post... thanks for observing!

Comment: Is `MyName` declared in `MyBaseClass` by any chance?

Comment: no, but i could if necessary to solve the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways. You can choose the one that you think is the most suitable for you.

**Keep using reflection**

```
PropertyInfo myNameProperty = listType.GetProperty("MyName");
myNameProperty.SetValue(valueToSet, field.Name);
```

**Use `dynamic`**:

```
dynamic valueToSet= Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
...
valueToSet.MyName = field.Name;
```

**Cast to superclass**

And apparently, as you said in your comments, you can declare `MyName` in `MyBaseClass`. This is an unusual thing to be able to do, but okay... Given that `MyName` is declared in `MyBaseClass`, you can cast `valueToSet` to `MyBaseClass`:

```
((MyBaseClass)valueToSet).MyName = field.Name;
```

Comment: is there a way of changing the hardcoded `"MyName"` to something more general and refactorable?

Comment: @anna Yes, `nameof(MyList<object>.MyName)`. The generic parameter `object` here doesn't matter because all you want is the string `"MyName"`.

Comment: Thanks! all your 3 solutions have worked fine for me!!